# Discord bot adding and waiting for reactions for a quiz game

Tags: python, api, discord, bots

I am writing a discord quiz bot using discordpy.
The bot sends a message that contains the questions and the 4 possible answers.
The bot also adds reactions to his message with the emojis 1️⃣, 2️⃣, 3️⃣ and 4️⃣.
The idea is, that the bot waits 30 seconds for people to click on one fo the reactions. If the clicked reaction is the correct/wrong answer, the bot replies with either correct or wrong. The bot should also stop waiting for new reaction once one person answered. Aka: Once a person clicks on one of the 4 reaction emojis, the bot should reply, and not process any future reactions to this message.

Currently, I got the bot to send the message (an embed) and add the reaction emojis to it. However, obtaining the results from the people is where I have problems with.

For one, the bot still seems to get triggered by his own reactions for some reason, even I excluded that in the check function. (Or so I thought).

In general, I'd like to have a very well structured approach for this. I am familiar with all the api calls/events, such as `on_message()` and `on_reaction_add()`, but I have trouble putting everything together correctly.

This is what I have so far:

```
@commands.command(name="quiz")
    async def on_command_quiz(ctx):

        #if ctx.message.author.bot:
        #    return   

        print("Quiz command!")
        quiz = QuizGame()

        # Send quiz
        reply = await ctx.message.channel.send(embed=quiz.format())

        # Add reply emojis
        for x in range(0, len(quiz.quiz_answers)):
            await reply.add_reaction(Utils.get_number_emoji_by_number(x + 1))
        print("Correct Answer:", quiz.quiz_correct_answer)

        # Evaluate replies
        async def check_answer(reaction, user):        
            emojis = ["1️⃣","2️⃣","3️⃣","4️⃣"]
            return user != ctx.message.author and str(reaction.emoji) in emojis

        # Wait for replies
        try:
            reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=30.0, check=check_answer)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            print("Timeout")
        else:
            if user != ctx.message.author:
                if str(reaction.emoji) == "1️⃣":
                    print("1")
                elif str(reaction.emoji) == "2️⃣":
                    print("2")
                elif str(reaction.emoji) == "3️⃣":
                    print("3")
                elif str(reaction.emoji) == "4️⃣":
                    print("4")
                else:
                    print("Unknown reaction")
```

How can I get this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several errors and some inaccuracies in your code; first I'll list them and then I'll show you what I think is the best way to set up this type of commands.
Please note that some of the following are not actual fixes but more efficient ways to organize your code.

-You should use **decorators** to define bot commands, instead of using functions like `on_command`:

```
@bot.command()
async def quiz(ctx)
```

-The `ctx` class provides the `channel` attribute already, so `ctx.message.channel` is kind of redundant, use `ctx.channel` instead.

Same applies for `ctx.message.author`.

-If the number of answers is always the same, then you can add the numeric emojis with a very simple for loop (also, there is no need to call `Utils` to get the relevant emojis):

```
for emoji in ["1️⃣","2️⃣","3️⃣","4️⃣"]:
    reply.add_reaction(emoji)
```

-The `check_answer` function is redundant as well, and logically wrong too.

It is redundant because there is no need to verify that the reaction emoji is one of the 4 available, since it will be determined later in the try block anyway.

It is logically wrong because it should return `True` if the user who added the reaction matches the author of the command, and not the opposite (you will notice that this will also prevent the bot from being triggered by its own reactions).

Then, there is no need for the function to be asynchronous.

```
def check_answer(reaction, user):
    return user == ctx.author
```

-Finally, the whole try-except-else block is not really functional here. In order for the bot to remain responsive until the first reaction of the specific user or until the 30 seconds timeout expires, you should integrate the try-except block into an **infinite while loop**:

```
while True:
    try:
        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=30, check=check_answer)
    
        # The following line is optional: it removes the reaction added by the user 
        # to let them react again with the same emoji; not really necessary in your case, 
        # but very helpful if your bot would still be responsive after the first reaction.
        await reply.remove_reaction(reaction, user) 

        # Here goes the if-else block of reactions.

    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print("Timeout")
```

Remember that somewhere in the try block you will have to stop the loop with a break statement when the operation is finished, otherwise it will continue indefinitely.

I am developing a Discord bot too and am still a beginner, so I hope I've been able to explain well.
Anyway, to sum it up, here is an example of how I would personally implement that command:

```
@bot.command()
async def quiz(ctx):

    print("Quiz command!")
    quiz = QuizGame()

    reply = await ctx.send(embed=quiz.format())

    emojis = ["1️⃣","2️⃣","3️⃣","4️⃣"]
    for emoji in emojis:
        await reply.add_reaction(emoji)

    def check_answer(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author

    while True:
        try:
            reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=30, check=check_answer)
            await reply.remove_reaction(reaction, user)

            # Shorter representation of that if-else block.
            if reaction.emoji in emojis:
                print(emojis.index(reaction.emoji) + 1)
                break
            else:
                print("Unknown reaction")

        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            print("Timeout")
```

Then of course you should define how to recognize the correct answer and how to notify the user.
If you need some clarification on what I wrote, feel free to comment on this answer and I will be happy to answer you.

Comment: Thanks. That helped a bunch. A quick side question if you don't mind. When defining own commands, i can set a name for them. However, spaces in them seem to cause execution of the wrong function. For example if you have a command function with the attribute name="test" and one with "test hello", for some reason the second function is always ignored, and only the first one is ran.

Comment: This happens because the `name` attribute represents the name of the function, and since it's not possible to define a function with a space character in its name, that character is discarded along with all the following ones.
In your case the string obtained matched another function, otherwise the code would have raised a `NameError`.

Comment: There are still ways to define a function with special characters in the name, but it would mean messing up the global symbol table of the main script, which is highly discouraged and really not worth the gain. I have multiple word commands for my bot too, like change prefix to name one, and I define them like 'change-prefix' or 'changeprefix'.

Comment: I assume in my case it would be best to use just one word for the command name, and the second one as argument? And then, depending on what the argument is, do different things.

Comment: That would definitely be a good workaround.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still experiencing the bot replying multiple times, when going with your suggested approach. Especially when !quiz is requested twice in a row, before an answer is given. Then the bot immediately responds to both. Then he seems to hang in the timeout loop or something, as he keeps spamming the timeout message forever and ever. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229605/discussion-between-max-shouman-and-kyu96).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really ignore the bots reaction, at least from what I can see in the code.
You can try the following method:

```py
            try:
                reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=15)
                while user == self.bot.user:
                    reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=15)
                if str(reaction.emoji) == "YourEmoji":
```

A `check` function could be:

```py
        reactions = "YourReactions"

        def check1(reaction, user):
            return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in [reactions]
```

Here we check if the reaction comes from the author of the command and also check if the emoji is in the `reactions` "list".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I now noticed some strange behaviour. When using your approach with the loop that keeps waiting, it sometimes gets called repeatadly, until it times out. Is there no better way of doing that. Basically everyone should be able to react, but stuff from the bot itself should be ignored. And just doing it in a while loop causes timeouts and hangs in the bot hmmm