# wait_for reaction_add always times out

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm working on a Discord bot that needs to wait for a reaction to be added to a message, but it looks like it always times out and just doesn't recognize a reaction being added. My code looks similar to answers to other questions about the same thing on StackOverflow but it still doesn't work somehow.

10 seconds after sending a message, the `timed out :(` string gets printed. In the meantime I have added a reaction to the message I sent, but nothing happens. It also doesn't call `check` because the emoji is never printed.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I've also looked at the Discord.py documentation and it looks like I'm doing it right.

**EDIT:** I've created a minimal reproducible example consisting of a main file and 1 cog: https://github.com/put/discord-testing-bot. This is what I do:

1. `python main.py`
2. Wait for "Test Cog loaded" to be printed
3. Make sure the bot is online
4. Send a message in a server where the bot is
5. Add a thumbs up emoji reaction within 10 seconds
6. Wait
7. See "timed out :(" printed in console.

The bot has all the permissions in my server:
[GIF of permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r7OU.gif)

**main.py**

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.none()
intents.guilds = True
intents.members = True
intents.emojis = True
intents.guild_messages = True
intents.guild_reactions = True

class TestBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix="^", help_command=None, max_messages=None, intents=intents)
        self.load_extension('test_cog')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot = TestBot()
    bot.run("[TOKEN HERE]", bot=True)
```

**test_cog.py**

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

class TestCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self._last_member = None

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author.bot or message.channel.type.name != 'text':
            return

        def check(reaction, user):
            print('a')
            return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == ""

        try:        
            reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check, timeout=10)
            print('success!')

        except asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError:
            print('timed out :(')

        except Exception as e:
            print(f'other error: {repr(e)}')

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(TestCog(bot))
    print("Test Cog loaded")
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66498347/discord-bot-adding-and-waiting-for-reactions-for-a-quiz-game/66499345#66499345) answer your question?

Comment: What does the rest of your code look like? I have placed your `on_message` in a cog and it does see reactions being added.

Comment: Do you have reaction and member intents enabled?

Comment: @Benjin I've updated my question to contain the entire cog! I've also prevented other cogs from loading in, just to make sure that is not the issue. It still doesn't seem to recognize reactions being added.

Comment: @FalseDev I've changed my bot to have both the Administrator intent, and I also turned the privileged "server members" intent on. Had it rejoin my test server just to be sure, and it still only times out, and never reached the `check` call :(

Comment: Do you have the `def setup(bot):` function at the end of your cog?

Comment: @Benjin Yup, setup function is present and is being called + adds the cog to the bot just fine.

Comment: I have tested your whole cog and it still works fine. Maybe update your question to include your main file as well. It will also be easier if you can turn your code into a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if your code is long.

Comment: @Benjin Thanks for taking the time to help! I've added a reproducible example in which this issue occurs for me, along with a step-by-step list of what I do. Also added GIF to show that the bot has all permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client):

> **max_messages** (Optional[`int`]) –
> The maximum number of messages to store in the internal message cache. This defaults to `1000`. Passing in `None` disables the message cache.

You are disabling the internal message cache with `max_messages=None`. Since the bot does not store the message, it cannot see any reactions added to it.

Change `None` to some integer value (default of `1000`), or just simply remove `max_messages=None` from your code.

Comment: Thanks so much! This did indeed fix it!

Comment: Where do you have to put the `max_message` ?

Comment: @Test It's an optional parameter that you can set when defining `discord.Client`. You don't need to set it as it has default value of `1000` but can change it to some other value if you want